# Higher Order Function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have written the following code. I know that a higher order function is a function that takes in another function and returns a function as a result. But I can't clearly distinguish a function if it is higher order or not. Is `sort` a higher order function? How do I find out if a function is higher order or not?

```
sortString :: String -> [String]
sortString x = sort (convertStringIntoList x)
```

Comment: Higher order functions can either take functions as arguments, or return functions (or both). Your function just takes a `String` and returns a list of `String`, so it's not higher order. However, if your sort function also took a function (like a comparison operator to determine ordering), then it would be higher-order.

Comment: In Haskell, all functions with at least two arguments return another function: `a -> b -> c` is the same as `a -> (b -> c)`. This means defining higher-order functions as returning a function is too broad--it would even include things like `(+)`!

Comment: Yeah, but that's the definition of higher-order. Haskell pretty much lives and breathes higher order functions.

Comment: Looking at Wikipedia, there are different definitions of a "higher-order function". Particularly, the one for typed lambda calculus defines them as any function in the form `(τ₁ → τ₂) → τ₃`, and is probably the most applicable one for Haskell.

Comment: When I need to add 1 to everything in a list, I use (+1) -- I am using (+) to return a procedure, so (+) is (or at least can be) a higher order procedure.  In Haskell, I think that in many cases, higher-orderness probably needs to be decided on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A higher-order function is a function that takes another function as an argument, produces another function as a result, or perhaps both.

The function in your question has a single argument that is a string, not a function. When applied, your function’s value is an array of strings, not a function. Therefore, it is an ordinary function.

A similar function that *is* higher order is

```
sortString :: (Char -> Char -> Ordering) -> String -> [String]
sortString cmp s = map (:[]) $ sortBy cmp s
```

The power of higher-order functions is the flexibility they provide. Providing different functions produces different results:

```
ghci> sortString compare "slkdjfs"
["d","f","j","k","l","s","s"]

ghci> sortString (flip compare) "slkdjfs"
["s","s","l","k","j","f","d"]
```

In case you aren’t familiar, `compare` provides an `Ordering` relative to its arguments, *e.g.*,

```
ghci> compare 'a' 'b'
LT
ghci> compare 'b' 'a'
GT
```

As you may have noticed, `flip` is itself another higher-order function that reorders or flips the arguments to another function. Using `flip` as in the code above allows us to sort the list in descending rather than ascending order.

Comment: Is it possible to make sortString a higher order function and get the following input and output                               Input:"telephone table carrying books"                            Output: ["books","carrying","table","telephone"]

Comment: @Sindu_ If that's input and output of `sortString`, it's not a higher order function. None of its input or outputs are functions. There's no need "to make it a higher order function" for it to do that.

Comment: @Sindu_ Take a look at Haskell's [`words`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:words) function.

Answer (score 2):

If sort takes the inputs convertStringIntoList and x, then it is higher order.
If x is first acted on by convertStringIntoList, then by sort, then sort is not a higher order function (the functions are just nested).

Based on the input and output types of sort (http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/sort_f.html) I'd say it's the first. (Also, based on the way it's formatted, this has to be the case.)
The type definition Ord a => [a] -> [a] means that the function takes a list of "a" and returns a list of "a", where a is a type of the class "Ord". Basically this just means it could be a Char, Double, Float, Int or Integer (http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/Ord_c.html). So the input cannot be a function.

In general you can find out if a function is higher order by looking up what its input and output types are. If either of these can be functions, then the function can be a higher order function.

You potentially have a bit of a grey area if the input may or may not be a function. For example, say you had a function that took an input and just returned that same output (pointless, but it's just an example). Then I would say that if you used a character as an input, it wouldn't be acting as a higher order function, but if you used a function as an input, then it would. Not sure about that part though, just my gut feeling.

Comment: Also, sortString definitely isn't a higher order function, since neither the input or the output are functions.